# Load table from SQL on action

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to fetch some data from a SQL database.

First I load the Primary Keys and some name to a dropdown. When the user clicks on an item, I'm trying to load a table with the rest of the values of the SQL object. I've read that the best way to do it is with Ajax, but turning it into a table-loading format is proving difficult.

Is there somewhere where I can find some reference for loading tables/data from Ajax and displaying it on the same page? (It is relatively simple if I do a POST to a new page, however I'd like to load it on the same page. Like showing a hidden .)

The SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Cliente (

    ClaveCliente        int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,

    Nombre              varchar(100) not null,
    RFC                 varchar(30) not null

);


CREATE TABLE DatosMes (

    ClaveDatos          int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    FechaDatos          date not null,

    Ingresos            smallint not null,
    Depositos           smallint not null,
    Transferencias      smallint not null,
    Cheques             smallint not null,
    Provisiones         smallint not null,
    Pasivos             smallint not null,
    Revision            smallint not null,
    Envio               smallint not null,
    Pago                smallint not null,

    Balanza             smallint not null,
    Catalogo            smallint not null,
    Informativa         smallint not null,
    ISR                 smallint not null


);

CREATE TABLE DatosMesCliente (

    ClaveDMC            int AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
    ClaveCliente        int not null,
    ClaveDatos          int not null,

    PRIMARY KEY (ClaveDMC),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClaveCliente) REFERENCES Cliente(ClaveCliente),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClaveDatos) REFERENCES DatosMes(ClaveDatos)
);
```

Sorry about the Spanish terms.

---

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var populateDatosMes = function(e) {
            var populateDatosMesTBody = function(r) {
                r = JSON.parse(r);
                var tbody = $("#DatosMesTable tbody");
                tbody.children().remove();
                if(r.length > 0) {
                    for(var i in r) {
                        tbody.append(
                            $("<tr>")
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Ingresos))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Depositos))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Transferencias))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Cheques))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Provisiones))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Pasivos))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Revision))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Envio))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Pago))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Balanza))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Catalogo))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Informativa))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].ISR))
                        );
                    }
                }
                else {
                    tbody.append(
                        $("<tr>")
                            .append($("<td>")
                                .text("No data to display.")
                                .attr("colspan", 13))
                    );
                }
            };

            var ClaveCliente = $("#ClienteSelectBox option:selected").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/query/DatosMes.php",
                /**
                 * Note:
                 * DatosMes.php should return a JSON format output similar to this:
                 * [
                 *  {
                 *      ClaveDatos: "",
                 *      FechaDatos: "",
                 *      Ingresos: "",
                 *      Depositos: "",
                 *      Transferencias: "",
                 *      Cheques: "",
                 *      Provisiones: "",
                 *      Pasivos: "",
                 *      Revision: "",
                 *      Envio: "",
                 *      Pago: "",
                 *      Balanza: "",
                 *      Catalogo: "",
                 *      Informativa: "",
                 *      ISR: ""
                 *  },
                 *  ...
                 *  {
                 *      ClaveDatos: "",
                 *      FechaDatos: "",
                 *      Ingresos: "",
                 *      Depositos: "",
                 *      Transferencias: "",
                 *      Cheques: "",
                 *      Provisiones: "",
                 *      Pasivos: "",
                 *      Revision: "",
                 *      Envio: "",
                 *      Pago: "",
                 *      Balanza: "",
                 *      Catalogo: "",
                 *      Informativa: "",
                 *      ISR: ""
                 *  }
                 * ]
                 *
                 */
                data: {
                    "ClaveCliente": ClaveCliente
                },
                success: populateDatosMesTBody,
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error on retrieval of DatosMes: " + textStatus);
                }
            });
        };

        var populateCliente = function(r) {
            var ClienteSelectBox = $("#ClienteSelectBox");
            if(ClienteSelectBox.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                ClienteSelectBox.children().remove();
                var r = JSON.parse(r);
                if(r.length > 0) {
                    for(var i in r) {
                        ClienteSelectBox.append(
                            $("<option>")
                                .val(r[i].ClaveCliente)
                                .text(r[i].Nombre)
                        );
                    }
                    ClienteSelectBox.bind("change", populateDatosMes);
                }
                else {
                    alert("No Cliente data retrieved.");
                }
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/query/Cliente.php",
            /**
             * Note:
             * Cliete.php should return a JSON format output similar to this:
             * [
             *  {
             *      ClaveCliente: 1,
             *      Nombre: "asdasd",
             *      RFC: "qweqwedsa"
             *  },
             *  {
             *      ClaveCliente: 2,
             *      Nombre: "asdasd",
             *      RFC: "qweqwedsa"
             *  },
             *  {
             *      ClaveCliente: 3,
             *      Nombre: "asdasd",
             *      RFC: "qweqwedsa"
             *  },
             *  ...
             *  {
             *      ClaveCliente: X,
             *      Nombre: "asdasd",
             *      RFC: "qweqwedsa"
             *  },
             * ]
             *
             */
            success: populateCliente,
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error on retrieval of Cliente: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="ClienteSelectBox"></select>
<br>
<br>
    <table id="DatosMesTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Ingresos</th>
                <th>Depositos</th>
                <th>Transferencias</th>
                <th>Cheques</th>
                <th>Provisiones</th>
                <th>Pasivos</th>
                <th>Revision</th>
                <th>Envio</th>
                <th>Pago</th>
                <th>Balanza</th>
                <th>Catalogo</th>
                <th>Informativa</th>
                <th>ISR</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Mind showing how the `SQL Object` looks like?

Comment: @Gideon I've added the tables.

Comment: Do you prefer to use `jquery`?

Comment: Add what `keys` connects the two tables?

Comment: Plus, what do you use on your backend? `PHP`? `Grails`?

Comment: @Gideon I've added the connection. I have no problem with using jQuery if it works. I am using php on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply, perhaps you've already found an answer. But this is *can* be the *front-end* answer to your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var populateDatosMes = function(e) {
            var populateDatosMesTBody = function(r) {
                var tbody = $("#DatosMes tbody").children().remove();
                if(r.length > 0) {
                    for(var i in r) {
                        tbody.append(
                            $("<tr>")
                                .append($("<th>").text(i + 1 + "."))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].ClaveDatos))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].FechaDatos))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Ingresos))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Depositos))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Transferencias))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Cheques))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Provisiones))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Pasivos))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Revision))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Envio))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Pago))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Balanza))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Catalogo))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].Informativa))
                                .append($("<td>").text(r[i].ISR))
                        );
                    }
                }
                else {
                    tbody.append(
                        $("<tr>")
                            .append($("<td>")
                                .text("No data to display.")
                                .attr("colspan", 16))
                    );
                }
            };

            var ClaveCliente = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/query/DatosMes.php",
                /**
                 * Note:
                 * DatosMes.php should return a JSON format output similar to this:
                 * [
                 *  {
                 *      ClaveDatos: "",
                 *      FechaDatos: "",
                 *      Ingresos: "",
                 *      Depositos: "",
                 *      Transferencias: "",
                 *      Cheques: "",
                 *      Provisiones: "",
                 *      Pasivos: "",
                 *      Revision: "",
                 *      Envio: "",
                 *      Pago: "",
                 *      Balanza: "",
                 *      Catalogo: "",
                 *      Informativa: "",
                 *      ISR: ""
                 *  },
                 *  ...
                 *  {
                 *      ClaveDatos: "",
                 *      FechaDatos: "",
                 *      Ingresos: "",
                 *      Depositos: "",
                 *      Transferencias: "",
                 *      Cheques: "",
                 *      Provisiones: "",
                 *      Pasivos: "",
                 *      Revision: "",
                 *      Envio: "",
                 *      Pago: "",
                 *      Balanza: "",
                 *      Catalogo: "",
                 *      Informativa: "",
                 *      ISR: ""
                 *  }
                 * ]
                 *
                 */
                params: {
                    "ClaveCliente": ClaveCliente
                },
                success: populateDatosMesTBody,
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error on retrieval of DatosMes: " + textStatus);
                }
            });
        };

        var populateCliente = function(r) {
            var ClienteSelectBox = $("#ClienteSelectBox");
            if(ClienteSelectBox.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                ClienteSelectBox.children().remove();
                if(r.length > 0) {
                    for(var i in r) {
                        ClienteSelectBox.append(
                            $("<option>")
                                .val(r[i].ClaveCliente)
                                .text(r[i].Nombre)
                                // or .text(r[i].RFC)
                        );
                    }
                    ClienteSelectBox.bind("change", populateDatosMes);
                }
                else {
                    alert("No Cliente data retrieved.");
                }
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/query/Cliente.php",
            /**
             * Note:
             * Cliete.php should return a JSON format output similar to this:
             * [
             *  {
             *      ClaveCliente: 1,
             *      Nombre: "asdasd",
             *      RFC: "qweqwedsa"
             *  },
             *  {
             *      ClaveCliente: 2,
             *      Nombre: "asdasd",
             *      RFC: "qweqwedsa"
             *  },
             *  {
             *      ClaveCliente: 3,
             *      Nombre: "asdasd",
             *      RFC: "qweqwedsa"
             *  },
             *  ...
             *  {
             *      ClaveCliente: X,
             *      Nombre: "asdasd",
             *      RFC: "qweqwedsa"
             *  },
             * ]
             *
             */
            success: populateCliente,
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error on retrieval of Cliente: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <select id="Cliente"></select>
    <table id="DatosMes">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ClaveDatos</th>
                <th>FechaDatos</th>
                <th>Ingresos</th>
                <th>Depositos</th>
                <th>Transferencias</th>
                <th>Cheques</th>
                <th>Provisiones</th>
                <th>Pasivos</th>
                <th>Revision</th>
                <th>Envio</th>
                <th>Pago</th>
                <th>Balanza</th>
                <th>Catalogo</th>
                <th>Informativa</th>
                <th>ISR</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to make some changes, but otherwise it helped a lot! I'll post the finished code on an edit.